# Can I make a normal (no voip) call with chromebook

Tags: chromebook

Can I make a normal (no voip) call with chromebook?

All I need is there sim card, mic and speakers, the only thing missing (or at least I was not able to find it) is the caller app.

Where can I find it (activate) or is there any app on the market providing this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

No.

There is no app that will turn your Chromebook into a cell phone.

Now, before somebody pipes in and screams "Skype!" or something similar, that is NOT the same thing.  Yes, there are different apps that you can (as you have already acknowledged) use to make VOIP calls.  You don't want to do that though.

Just because you can slide a SIM card into the device does NOT mean that it is capable of being a cell phone, regardless of what software you install on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; it seems like an artificial limitation to be hacked into.

Comment: there might be some way to do this if you get a usb cellular chip.