# are bluetooth headset calls on a 3G Chromebook possible?

Tags: bluetooth, voip, chromebook, google-chrome-os, 3g

Would it be possible to use a [bluetooth](https://www.plantronics.com/ca/en/product/voyager-5200) headset to make a cell-phone call?

Or is the 3g capability [only](https://superuser.com/q/449405/55747) for data?

I'm inferring this is an OS limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (most likely) a hardware limitation and the 3G module is only capable of transmitting data.

Prior to the latest versions of 4G voice and data over the mobile network were handled completely separately and modems had two inputs as a result: a data input and an audio input.

The audio input needed to do a lot of work figuring out what audio codecs the cellular network supported and converting line-level audio into those formats in order to push them onto what is effectively a land-line style digitised circuit switched network. At the fundamental networking level audio and data were handled very differently.

For a "data only" device such as a 3G dongle or modem built into a tablet they could simply not bother wiring up the audio, assuming it was even available in the chosen 3G chip. Leaving out all of the audio functionality would simplify modem chip design itself so it would save money to have a device that was incapable of audio.

The reason for the separation of audio and data is because originally the network was a switched audio network. Passing data through it was an optional "bolt-on" to the network. For more info see [Wikipedia: GSM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM). The result is that voice-only or data-only devices are normal and expected as a feature of the network they run over.

Unless you use Voice Over IP (VoIP) programs such as Skype, Discord or any other number of services,  you will almost certainly not be able to use your built in modem for voice calls.

The latest versions of 4G support sending voice as data, effectively becoming VOIP and is known as VoLTE - Voice over LTE.